# I can't get the minify-maven-plugin to just remove whitespace and comments from JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, maven, ecmascript-6, minify

I don't want anything other than removing whitespace and comments in the first place but the plugin outputs something "clever" like:

```
for(var $jscomp$iter$1=
$jscomp.makeIterator(ribbonSet),$jscomp$key$ribbon=$jscomp$iter$1.next();
```

which the browser complains about (that's not the point anyway).

The original code is a for of loop

```
for (let ribbon of ribbonSet) {
```

The plugin conf bit in the pom is like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>minify</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>minify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                        <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
                        <webappSourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</webappSourceDir>
                        <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                        <closureCompilationLevel>WHITESPACE_ONLY</closureCompilationLevel>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I've tried changing the configuration adding this:

```
<closureCompilationLevel>WHITESPACE_ONLY</closureCompilationLevel>
<closureLanguageIn>ECMASCRIPT6</closureLanguageIn>
<jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
<yuiDisableOptimizations>true</yuiDisableOptimizations>
<yuiNoMunge>true</yuiNoMunge>
<charset>UTF-8</charset>
```

Still the same output.

I've tried using the yui engine:

```
<jsEngine>YUI</jsEngine>
```

But then it complains about the `for(let x of y)` during compilation. It's clear that the plugin is buggy (or the documentation is wrong).

Is there a way to tell it to just mind the whitespace and comments?

Note: I removed this configuration options above, but these are irrelevant in theory.

```
                      <webappTargetDir>${project.build.directory}/minify</webappTargetDir>
                        <cssSourceIncludes>
                            <cssSourceInclude>**/*.css</cssSourceInclude>
                        </cssSourceIncludes>
                        <cssSourceExcludes>
                            <cssSourceExclude>**/*.min.css</cssSourceExclude>
                        </cssSourceExcludes>
                        <jsSourceIncludes>
                            <jsSourceInclude>**/*.js</jsSourceInclude>
                        </jsSourceIncludes>
                        <jsSourceExcludes>
                            <jsSourceExclude>**/*.min.js</jsSourceExclude>
                        </jsSourceExcludes>
                        <cssSourceDir>resources/css</cssSourceDir>
                        <jsSourceDir>resources/js</jsSourceDir>
```